# Proper Way to Conduct Statistical Test on Businesses with Invoice Growth/Loss

Tags: statistical-significance, python, statistical-power

I have a set of businesses that have invoices from clients each day. I use this year-over-year to find how transactions have grown each year, i.e. 2 invoices Sep 2021 and 3 invoices Sep 2022 is (3-2)/2 = 50% yoy txn growth.

I want to find a method to discern (preferably in Python) if a business has significantly more or significantly less invoices each month than the average number of monthly transactions across all businesses.

I'm looking at the calculation for statistical power but unsure how to use it in this case.

My original data would look like:

```
business|time_value|txns|yoy_txn_growth
1111    |2022-02-01|10  |null
1111    |2023-02-01|11  |0.10
1111    |2022-03-01|10  |null
1111    |2023-03-01|12  |0.20
2222    |2022-02-01|10  |null
2222    |2023-02-01|13  |0.30
2222    |2022-03-01|10  |null
2222    |2023-03-01|14  |0.40
...
```

I'm looking to arrive at a meaningful answer of how many invoices and/or businesses need to exist to have a 0.05 significance. Not sure if I need to decide what difference in txns/yoy_txn_growth from the mean would be significant but it can be 1 standard deviation.

Could someone outline the steps I should follow for this usecase to derive what number of businesses and/or invoices I would need to find a meaningful result? The null hypothesis can either be 1) Practice X has significantly more/significantly less txns than the mean this month 2) Practice X has significantly more/significantly less yoy_txn_growth than the mean this month.

Comment: Although there's nothing the matter with this inquiry, it's *strange.* Being able to *detect* an above- or below-average business would seem to have far less value than *studying how the businesses vary* in a quantitative way.  Are you sure your ultimate objective really requires any kind of formal hypothesis testing?

Comment: I do study other dimensions about over-performing/under-performing businesses w/ high/low respectively yoy txn growth for any given month relative to the rest of the businesses. But I don't have grounding if above/below average in my subjective interpretation is remarkable in a statistically significant way based upon the number of businesses or invoices I'm considering. The latter is the piece I'm trying to resolve, "What should my sample size be by number of businesses to generally begin to start looking for significance?" I know this relates to statistical power but unsure how to begin...

Comment: "Looking for significance" isn't much of an objective.  "Significance" in this technical context means "able to detect a difference."  In science sometimes that can be valuable, but it would seem to be much less so in a business context where the *amount of the difference* might be more relevant. Moreover, .05 significance exists by *fiat:* you decide that and then select a sample size accordingly.

Comment: Yes that is the problem statement in this case posed to me and not something I have control over unfortunately. The question is how many businesses are necessary to draw statistically significant conclusions about invoice growth/decline. How I draw those conclusions and what about invoice I analyze is what I have more control over.

Comment: That question is not answerable with the information given because "draw statistically insignificant conclusions" is too vague.  Sometimes you have to educate the person who makes requests that are unreasonable or nonsensical.

Comment: Can you help me understand why this isn't possible in more statistical theory terms and not business terms? Say, analogously, I have a cluster of wires from different businesses and when they work well they send signals each day at different rates, each time I see a signal I write "TXN" and the business and the datetime. Why, statistically, is there no way to find how many wires I'd need to have to find which ones are firing abnormally greater/less than the mean? I just want to know what variables make that currently unanswerable (I need to make good assumptions for) and a example path forward

Comment: It comes down to finding a clear, quantitative way to ascribe a meaning to "a business has significantly more or significantly less invoices each month than the average number of monthly transactions." "Significantly" implies several things: (a) some probability model, (b) a specific form of "average," and (c) a specified confidence level.  The crucial thing is (a), because this is potentially a complicated situation with many businesses whose invoice counts vary in complex ways over time.  Once you formulate that you can probably make some headway.